# Is there a way to make a user-defined conversion for a class that I can't write code to?

Tags: c#, monogame

So I have two classes provided by MonoGame: Color and Vector4. These two classes can be interpreted as the same thing: a Vector4 can store the values R, G, B and A of Color. I'm trying to write an implicit (explicit is fine too if that's required) conversion operator to go from Color to Vector4. How can I do that without writing to MonoGame's source code?

Trying to define one in an unrelated class leads to the much dreaded "User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type", and doing it inside the namespace itself, not a class, leads to even more scary errors.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to sneak in somewhere:

```
public static explicit operator Vector4(Color color)
{
    return new Vector4(color.R, color.G, color.B, color.A);
}
```

How would I go about sneaking in the above code? If that isn't possible, is there a workaround?

Comment: That's a weird interpretation. A Vector4 can hold negative values and values above 1, which don't make sense for RGB

Comment: Would extension methods for converting between types be acceptable?

Comment: I believe you'd have to write your own classes for this, convert the `Vector4` or `Color` to one of those, then compare. Seems like a lot of work when you could just add an extension method so you could do `vector4variable.AsColor()` or `colorVariable.AsVector4()`...

Comment: Camilo Terevinto, I use it to pass it on to a shader, which has to use Vector4. I don't mention the limitations of Color, because I trust myself to not go into negatives and above 1. I could change the operator to restrict this, but that doesn't change the question.

Comment: Knowing that, the answer by @JSteward is the best you can get

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto,  Floats are the standard representation of colors in shaders.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you could get is an extension method on each type you want to convert.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public Vector4 ToVector4(this Color color)
    {
        return //do conversion to vector4
    }

    public Color ToColor(this Vector4 vector)
    {
        return //do conversion to Color
    }
}
```

That said not all `Vector4` could necessarily represent a color as @Camilo Terevinto pointed out.

Comment: MonoGame has this function already defined in Color.  The reverse can be done on the constructor `public Color(Vector4 color)`

Answer (score 0):

MonoGame's `Color` class already contains a `.ToVector4()` instance method.

See [Color.cs](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/d9e38a5ffe48aaa4c2313cc87e07b007420115de/MonoGame.Framework/Color.cs#L1786) in the MonoGame source git.
It returns a `Vector4` with each of its values between 0 and 1.

The return trip `Vector4 to Color` is provided by a `Color` Constructor that takes a `Vector4` as its only argument.

This value can be directly passed to shader functions.

I realize you were looking for an explicit cast for this.

It is a fairly simple process:

1. Download the MonoGame source using [git](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame.git).
2. Add the following lines within the class in MonoGame.Framework/Color.cs

   ```
   public static explicit operator Vector4(Color color)
   {
      return new Vector4(color.R / 255f, color.G / 255f, color.B / 255f, color.A / 255f);
   }
   ```
3. Compile the framework for each of your target platforms.

   If you are using Visual Studio, it is easier to include the MonoGame project as part of your solution, and add it in your project's References(while removing the existing MonoGame References).
4. Copy the Framework Dlls on top of the existing ones in your target directory.
5. Rebuild your project. In some instances, you may have to repeat step 4.